# .XML Sitemaps and HTML Sitemaps Clarification

Tags: html, xml, seo, sitemap

I've got a website with about 170 pages and I want to create an effective Sitemap for it as it is long due. The website is internally linked very well but I still want to take advantage of creating a sitemap to allow SE's to crawl my site easier and to hopefully increase my websites PR. Though I am slightly confused to what I must do: Is it necessary to create a .xml sitemap AND a HTML Sitemap (both)? ... Because I've never worked with .xml ... where do I put this file once it's created? In the Root folder? So I assume that this sitemap.xml is ONLY to be read by spiders and NOT by website visitors. IE: No visitor on my website is going to visit the page sitemap.xml, am I correct? ... Hence why I should also create an HTML sitemap (sitemap.htm)?

Comment: HTML sitemaps are for visitors to see what pages you have. There is no requirement that it be named `sitemap.htm`. XML sitemaps are for search engine spiders to know what pages you want them to index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally no user will see your sitemap.xml, it's there for the robots and spiders, you're right. You put it on the root directory of the site.

In theory, a sitemap.xml should be enough, no need of a sitemap.html... but sitemap.html are useful for SEO, and some users like to use them to navigate the site. If you do a sitemap.xml, the .html can be automatically generated from the xml, you don't need to pass a lot of time to generate it, so IMHO you should still do both of them.

Comment: Just another Question. The sitemap.xml - would it be necessary to break that document up if you have more than 100 links? Or does that only apply to the HTML sitemap?

Comment: According to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps#Sitemap_limits), the limit is 50 000 URLs and 10 MB per sitemap.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm sure that is allowed but is it the best practice SEO-wise. Great, thanks for your help otherwise, I'll see what I can find out regarding my question just above and post it here in-case it helps other people wanting to know.

Comment: I meant that you don't need to cut  sitemap.xml. Splitting the sitemap for SEO-wise reasons would only be interesting for the HMTL

Comment: Actually Google suggests using an HTML sitemap as well as an XML sitemap when you can because the HTML links in an HTML sitemap they'll always crawl while a sitemap there's no guarantee. Either Matt Cutts or John M from WMT posted about this.